# c++ qt qabstracttablemodel subclass chrashes when underlying qmap is updated

Tags: c++, qt, subclassing, qabstracttablemodel

i am having great trouble with the update of a custom qabstracttablemodel.
i want to have a tableview that shows the prices of several stocks. i get the prices from a local server i control. this setup is for testing purposes. the pricing information is received in a worker thread.

i have subclassed the qabstracttablemodel in the following way:

PriceModel.h:

```
class PriceModel : public QAbstractTableModel {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    PriceModel( QObject* parent = 0 );

    void setPriceMap( const QMap<QString, ITick*> &curTickMap );
    int rowCount( const QModelIndex &parent ) const;
    int columnCount( const QModelIndex &parent ) const;
    QVariant data( const QModelIndex &index, int role ) const;
    QVariant headerData( int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role ) const;
private:
    QMap<QString, ITick*> currentTicks;
    QString stockAt( int offset ) const;
};
```

PriceModel.cpp

```
#include "PriceModel.h"

PriceModel::PriceModel( QObject* parent ) : QAbstractTableModel( parent ) {
}

int PriceModel::rowCount( const QModelIndex& parent ) const {
    return this->currentTicks.count();
}

int PriceModel::columnCount( const QModelIndex& parent ) const {
    return 4;
}

QString PriceModel::stockAt( int offset ) const {
    return ( currentTicks.begin() + offset ).key();
}

QVariant PriceModel::data( const QModelIndex& index, int role ) const {
    if ( !index.isValid() ) {
        return QVariant();
    }
    if ( role == Qt::TextAlignmentRole ) {
        return int( Qt::AlignRight | Qt::AlignVCenter );
    } else if ( role == Qt::DisplayRole ) {
        QString stock = stockAt( index.row() );
        int i = index.column();
        switch ( i ) {
            case 0 : return currentTicks.value( instrument )->getTime().toString( "hh:mm:ss:zzz" );
            case 1 : return currentTicks.value( instrument )->getBid();
            case 2 : return currentTicks.value( instrument )->getAsk();
            case 3 : return currentTicks.value( instrument )->getBidVolume();
            case 4 : return currentTicks.value( instrument )->getAskVolume();
        }
    }
    return QVariant();
}

QVariant PriceModel::headerData( int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role )  const {
    if ( role != Qt::DisplayRole ) {
        return QVariant();
    }
    if ( orientation == Qt::Horizontal ) {
        switch ( section ) {
            case 0 : return QString( "Time" );
            case 1 : return QString( "Bid" );
            case 2 : return QString( "Ask" );
            case 3 : return QString( "Bid Volume" );
            case 4 : return QString( "Ask Volume" );
        }
    } else {
        return instrumentAt( section )->getCurrencyPairWithDelimiter();
    }
    return QVariant();
}

void PriceModel::setTickMap( const QMap<QString,ITick*>& curTickMap ) {
    beginResetModel();
    this->currentTicks = curTickMap;
    endResetModel();
}
```

the model populates the tableview when i call the setTickMap( qmap<...> ) method and all the different stocks are shown just as expected. ( initializing the data in my model is working fine )

the problem arises when i want to call the setTickMap( qmap<...> ) method again. the application crashes and i do not understand why nor do i get a significant error message - namely a segvault.

on a crash in debug configuration netbeans opens a tab named "Disassemlby" with following content:

```
QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**)+50: add    %ebx,%r15d
QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**)+85: testb $0x4,0x20(%rax)
QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**)+89: jne 0x7ffff63f4df8 <QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**)+536>
QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**)+102: add    0x6c(%rsp),%ebx
QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**)+118: mov    %ebx,0x2c(%rsp)
QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**)+106: movq   $0x0,0x40(%rsp)
QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**)+95: mov    0x31c19a(%rip),%rdx        # 0x7ffff6710de0
QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**)+115: mov    (%rdx),%rax
QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**)+122: test   %rax,%rax
QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**)+125: je     0x7ffff63f4c72 <QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**)+146>
QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**)+127: lea    0x40(%rsp),%rdx
QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**)+132: test   %r13,%r13
QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**)+135: mov    %ebx,%esi
QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**)+137: mov    %r12,%rdi
QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**)+140: cmovne %r13,%rdx
QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, QMetaObject const*, int, void**)+144: callq  *%rax
```

i sandwiched the map assignment in the beginResetModel() methods but that does not seem to work as i just get a crashing application. odly enough this works at the first call of the setter method. this makes me assume that it is a quite stupid mistake. i think as the first call works fine we can rule out that it has something to do with inter-thread-communication problems.

this model is not supposed to be edited by the user through the GUI and i am aware that i could have used the tablewidget to just display the data but i am not sure if there is going to be another view that will share this models information. the map with the current prices is not going to be very big ( 25 items tops ) so i am not uncomfortable to reset the model on every new price coming in.

thanks in advance and i hope someone can help me with this
micropor

Comment: Are you sure this compiles? `currentTicks` is a `QMap<QString, ITick*>` while your `setTickMap` has as argument a `QMap<IInstrument*,ITick*>`.

Comment: i am sorry but to make the problem easier i changed my custom interface IInstrument to something known like a qstring...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow my stupidity knows no bounds...

I fixed the problem and it had nothing to do with the tickmodel itself. The codesamples provided work just fine. I was apparently just too stupid to make sure the correct modelpointer is used.

This is sufficient:

```
void PriceModel::setTickMap( const QMap<QString,ITick*>& curTickMap ) {
    this->currentTicks = curTickMap;
    reset();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are displaying real time tickdata I'd recommend approaching the data storage.  Since you are only displaying 5 items from the tick you might want to consider something other then a QMap may be arrays since your universe might be fairly standardized during the trading day.

Also I would have to assume that the code is multi-threaded and the `curTickMap` may change during the `setTickMap` as it is likely that you are not doing the model reset on every tick.

And as webclectic pointed out the code you have posted is unlikely to compile.